# Control Error Shell Exec

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting-language

I Have the following code for a VBScript in Windows

```
Dim strOutPut
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(MyApp.exe)
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
strOutPut = strOutPut & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine() &  vbCrLf 
Loop
```

In some computers MyApp.exe (I tested manually) trows a warning.
My problem is when this happens the objExecObject comes empty and the strOutPut is not populated with the thext provided by the MyApp.exe.

If I manually run MyApp.exe I see the warning and also the text that I want (Is just a warning).

So, My question is how to execute

```
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(MyApp.exe)
```

And ignore the warning so it still populates the variable at

```
strOutPut = strOutPut & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine() &  vbCrLf
```

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: What you ask is stupid. The answer NO. You can't use an object that didn't create. There's no code to execute. Fix your computer, it's not a programming problem.

Comment: One normally specifies full paths to files so computer configuration is irrelevant.

Comment: I can execute MyApp.exe, it runs and inside of the cmd line has an error and additional information, MyApp.exe is not crashing...

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly work anywhere. `MyApp.exe` needs to be in double quotes, and if the program doesn't reside in the current working directory the string must also include the path to the executable.